# Field not hiding from tree view using Fields_view_get

Tags: python, field, openerp-7, invisible

I have written a code to update my treeview according to input. it is basically working using `context`. My fields_view_get method is like this:

```
def fields_view_get(self,cr,uid,view_id=None,view_type='form',context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    if context is None:
        context={}
    res=super(product_product,self).fields_view_get(cr,uid,view_id=view_id,view_type=view_type,context=context,toolbar=toolbar,submenu=submenu)
    doc=etree.XML(res['arch'])  
    if context.get('parent',False):
        parent=context.get('parent',False)
        if parent==85: ####Vehicle
        print etree.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True)
            for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='size_furn']"):
            node.set('invisible','1')
            res['arch']=etree.tostring(doc)
    print "\n\n\n\nxml ",res['arch']
    return res
```

Here i am updating visibility of `size_furn`

I have printed output on console. here is `res['arch']` before change

```
<tree colors="red:  state in ('draft', 'end', 'obsolete');black: state not in ('draft', 'end', 'obsolete')" string="Asset Products">

                <!--    <field name="default_code"/> -->
                    <field name="name" modifiers="{&quot;required&quot;: true}"/>
                <!-- ############################################################ -->
                    <field name="product_code" modifiers="{&quot;readonly&quot;: true}"/>
                <!-- ############################################################   -->
 <field name="state" invisible="True" modifiers="{&quot;tree_invisible&quot;: true}"/>
<field name="size_furn" invisible="0" modifiers="{&quot;tree_invisible&quot;: false}"/>
                </tree>
```

here is the changes on `res['arch']`

```
<tree colors="red:  state in ('draft', 'end', 'obsolete');black: state not in ('draft', 'end', 'obsolete')" string="Asset Products">

                <!--    <field name="default_code"/> -->
                    <field name="name" modifiers="{&quot;required&quot;: true}"/>
                <!-- ############################################################ -->
                    <field name="product_code" modifiers="{&quot;readonly&quot;: true}"/>
                <!-- ############################################################   -->
 <field name="state" invisible="True" modifiers="{&quot;tree_invisible&quot;: true}"/>
<field name="size_furn" invisible="1" modifiers="{&quot;tree_invisible&quot;: false}"/>
                </tree>
```

As we can see xml is updating, but problem is changes are not visible on openerp application. I can view this field in any case. i tried to use `True` and `False` too. but it didnot work. any way to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<field name="field_name" invisible="context.get('flag',False)" />
```

you can pass context to list view using action which is bind to the list view.

```
<record id="action_account_tree1" model="ir.actions.act_window">
   <field name="name">Analytic Items</field>
   <field name="res_model">account.analytic.line</field>
   <field name="view_type">form</field>
   <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
   <field name="context">{'flag':True}</field>
</record>
```

No need to override fields_view_get if your aim is to hide fields from list view based on context then.